# Trigger breakpoints in Razor file generated by RazorGenerator

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my ASP.NET MVC project all Razor views are processed by custom tool 'RazorGenerator'. However, breakpoints inside generated files are not triggered, so I am not sure if these files are used at all. I received few exception stacktraces from production, but the lines referenced are far from the `Execute` method in generated file.

I have found some code to register `PrecompiledMvcEngine`, but I still can't say if generated files are being used. In Debug, I get correct engine, when I feed `Layout.cshtml` into `ViewEngines`, but all breakpoints hit `cshtml` file. What do I do wrong?

```
public static class PreApplicationStartCode
{
    private static bool startMethodExecuted;

    public static void Start()
    {
        if (startMethodExecuted)
        {
            return;
        }

        var engine = new PrecompiledMvcEngine(typeof(PreApplicationStartCode).Assembly)
        {
            UsePhysicalViewsIfNewer = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal
        };

        ViewEngines.Engines.Insert(0, engine);

        // StartPage lookups are done by WebPages. 
        VirtualPathFactoryManager.RegisterVirtualPathFactory(engine);

        startMethodExecuted = true;
    }
}
```